# Ошибка при хостинге сайта

Tags: asp.net-core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Проблема такая. Захостил сайт написанный на ASP.NET Core MVC, но при попытке перехода на него ошибка: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error.
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Скрин приложу. Пробовал с двух хостингов и один и тот же сценарий. Как я понимаю проблема с файлом web.config, которого у ASP.NET Core по умолчанию нет, но после того, как я заливаю файлы сайта через FTP, он появляется. Заливаю файлы на хостинг из VS 2019.
Прошу, помогите пожалуйста понять, что делать в такой ситуации!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Если у кого то будет подобная ошибка, то просите включить на хостинге web deploy. По FTP не залить, но можно через web deploy быстро и без проблем заливать.